# Triple map including 2 keys

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a structure containing 3 fields, two `int`s *(let's call them **A** and **B**)* and a `bool` *(**C**)*.

I want to create a sort of array of that struct and be able to access it through any of the keys (A or B), getting the hole object (with A, B and C) in return.
I won't need to do something like "getting all the object for which the bool is true", if that makes any difference.

Obviously, both key are unique and the bool can't be, but I thought I'd mention it for the sake of clarity.

If there was no A or B, it would be a simple `std::map<int, bool>`.

The only solution I currently see is to make a wrapper containing 2 `set`s and a `vector`.
Is there any way to make my life easier?

*NB: It will contain at most a hundred tuples, so performance should not be an issue. Linear access is acceptable.*

To make it even clearer, here is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
foobar<int, int, bool> array;  // or something along those lines

array.add(1, 101, true);
array.add(2, 102, false);

array.getA(1); // returns first object
array.getA(2);   // returns second object
array.getB(102); // returns second object again
```

Comment: If this is your real requirement (int, int, bool) and not a cut down example, I would just do it with two maps (`map<int,bool>`), one for A and one for B.

Comment: It is a cut down example, but most importantly this solution would need a wrapper anyways to keep the 2 `bool`s in sync.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html). It'll allow you to declare a container with multiple indices.

```
struct MultiIDStruct
{
    size_t idA;
    size_t idB;
    std::string name;
};

namespace mul = boost::multi_index;

boost::multi_index_container< MultiIDStruct, 
    mul::indexed_by< 
        mul::ordered_unique< mul::member< MultiIDStruct, size_t, &MultiIDStruct::idA > >,
        mul::ordered_unique< mul::member< MultiIDStruct, size_t, &MultiIDStruct::idB > > 
    > > data;
```

<sup>(Used namespace "shortcut" as per Rapptz suggestion)</sup>

For example here you have a `multi_index` container of `MultiIDStruct` for which there are two unique orderings, one on `idA` (which is a member of `MultiIDStruct`) and a second on `idB` (which is also a member).

The template parameters seem like a handful at first but they're not so bad once you understand how they work.

Comment: You can shorten this by doing `namespace mul = boost::multi_index` or something.

Comment: This looks perfect. I'll have a more in-depth look at it tomorrow and decide whether I prefer this or RyanMcK's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion to split it up into two maps is certainly a bit simpler, but if you want some more flexibility and can use C++11 for features like `std::tuple`, you might try something of the form:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class foobar
{
public:
    void add(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)
    {
        m1[t1] = std::make_tuple(t1, t2, t3);
        m2[t2] = std::make_tuple(t1, t2, t3);
    }

    std::tuple<T1,T2,T3> getA(T1 t1)
    {
        return m1[t1];
    }

    std::tuple<T1,T2,T3> getB(T2 t2)
    {
        return m2[t2];
    }

private:
    std::map<T1,std::tuple<T1,T2,T3>> m1;
    std::map<T2,std::tuple<T1,T2,T3>> m2;
};

int main()
{
    foobar<int, int, bool> array;  // or something along those lines

    array.add(1, 101, true);
    array.add(2, 102, false);

    auto res1 = array.getA(1); // returns first object
    auto res2 = array.getA(2);   // returns second object
    auto res3 = array.getB(102); // returns second object again

    std::cout << std::get<0>(res1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(res2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(res3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[A working example](http://ideone.com/YfcN1k) gives the output 1, 102, 0 (false).

Comment: Well, that's pretty much the wrapper I had in mind, although I though it'd be much bigger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know I didn't give the detail implementation. But I'm just suggesting a logic with two maps. What's wrong with it? Why do I get downvoted?

```
struct s
{
int i;
int j;
bool b;
};

std::map<int, int> mapA;
std::map<int, s> mapB;

const s& getA(int i)
{
    return mapB[mapA[i]];
}

const s& getB(int j)
{
    return mapB[j];
}

void add(int i, int j, bool b)
{
    s p;
    p.i=i;
    p.j=j;
    p.b=b;
    mapB[j]=p;
    mapA[i]=j;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a downwoter, but you can't get whole object for `b` key.

Comment: @soon what is "hole object"?

Comment: It was a typo. Whole object.

Comment: @soon I have updated my answer. What do you mean by "can't get whole object"?

Comment: Even after edit you can gel only `bool` part of object for `b` key.

Comment: @soon I see. I have misunderstood OP's request.

Comment: No. What is `p` and why is it needed?

Comment: @soon oops, sorry for the mistake. It's a local variable.

Comment: Nice. But why is it needed? Also, you got a memory leak here.

Comment: @soon Oh..I thought map would accept a reference..But do you mean it actually copies the data?

Comment: I also suggest return const references, since you can't change values - it will break search.

Comment: Yes. Will be better to put all inside a class to avoid global variables. Also, while other answers are preferable(they are better, no offence), I see no reason for downvote now. Compensated.

Comment: @soon That's very kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, and a different solution!

Have two hash functions on A and B, giving h1(A) and h2(B) such, that they do not give equal values. Example:

```
uint32_t A;
uint32_t B;

uint64_t hashA(uint32_t value)
{ return ((uint64_t)value) << 32; }

uint64_t hashB(uint32_t value)
{ return (uint64_t)value; }
```

Put all your stuff into std::map so that hashA and hashB have the same value for bool. Access it with either hashA or hashB.

Example: A = 0x10000001, B = 0x20000002, C = true

hashA(A): 0x1000000100000000
hashB(B): 0x0000000020000002

map:
0x1000000100000000 -> true
0x0000000020000002 -> true